# Messages with three dashes get cut off

Tags: ios, messages, bug

My wife sent me a video of my son saying something, to which I responded:

```
What's he saying? Mommy read --- book?
```

A few seconds after I sent the message, the text "book?" (and possibly the last dash) disappeared from my sent message. My wife says that she originally saw the word "book", but when she went back and looked, it had been removed for her too.

Does this happen for anyone else? Is this intended, or a bug?

Comment: What kind of device did you send this from, on what version of iOS?

Comment: @timothymh - My wife and I each have an iPhone 6s. I'm using iOS 11.0.2, and she's using at least iOS 11.0.1.

Comment: Go to settings > general > keyboard and turn off Smart Punctuation and see if problem still occurs

Comment: @TomGewecke - it appears to have fixed it on my side. I'm waiting to hear from my wife to see if it's working on hers. Why would Smart Punctuation cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with Apple's Smart Punctuation, as [explained here](http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/09/26/tips-turn-off-ios-11-smart-punctuation-to-avoid-data-entry-problems). To avoid this issue in the future, go to Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> switch off Smart Punctuation. This will also remove the "press space twice to make a period" functionality, unfortunately.

From using the iOS 11.1 beta, it appears that this issue will be fixed in the 11.1 update.

Comment: Even when fixed, having Smart Punctuation turned on will cut allowed SMS messages to 70 characters, so many users will want to keep it off.